# Composer, class not found

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, composer-php

I installed composer in my CodeIgniter project, downloaded 2 packages: Aura/Sql and Aura/SqlQuery

this is my code from index.php file

```
require_once ROOTPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aura\Sql\ExtendedPdo;
$db = new ExtendedPdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', array(), array());
var_dump($db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM sh_users'));

use Aura\Sql_Query\QueryFactory;
$query_factory = new QueryFactory('mysql');

require_once BASEPATH . 'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

both fragments are copied from documentation

var_dump gives perfect result, but QueryFactory gives me error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aura\Sql_Query\QueryFactory' not found in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeigniter\public\admin\index.php on line 83
```

and i have no idea why. all vendors are downloaded and all php files are there, but it seems autoload doesnt load it. why?

Comment: What does your `composer.json` file look like?

Comment: You should read the documentation for the branch / version you're actually using. Try this instead of the *master* `README.md` - https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql_Query/blob/rename/README.md

Comment: The problem was due to the namespace. It is SqlQuery which is changed before another release. So may be some beta was having the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the file structure on disk; you may actually want to be including `Aura\SqlQuery\QueryFactory`, instead of something under the `Sql_Query` namespace. It may be something as simple as that. I've encountered issues when I've forgotten to rename the class in a PSR-0 compliant path such that it matches the file name, so if in fact the contents on the disk are in:

`Aura\SqlQuery\QueryFactory` but your use statement is `Aura\Sql_Query\QueryFactory`, you'll run into a problem.

As mentioned below in the comments, it appears that the Aura devs have two branches, the master branch on the Githup project [auraphp/Aura.Sql_Query](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql_Query/blob/develop-2/src/QueryFactory.php) still has the directory structure as `Sql_Query` where as the default package, served by packagist, serves the `dev-rename` branch which replaces `Sql_Query` with `SqlQuery`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Seems the Aura devs decided to remove the underscore in their `dev-rename` branch which is what I bet OP is using (it's the default version on packagist)

Comment: @Phil Exactly what I was thinking right now. [Github master](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql_Query/blob/develop-2/src/QueryFactory.php) still has the underscore…

Comment: Thank you guys for the support. FYI : @nietonfir the master is just there. Only develop is for v1 and develop-2 is for version2 development happens. Don't use master branch.